# bash if statement with null value

Tags: bash, null, conditional-statements

my if condition with gt compare value and also if the value is null, but I want that gt compare null value, I just want that he compare only value

```
 res=''
 toto=5
 if [[  "$toto" -gt "$res"  ]]; then
    ... 
   else
    ...
   fi
 fi
```

solution is that, but not very good

```
 if [[ ! -z "$res"  ]]; then
   if [[  "$toto" -gt "$res"  ]]; then
     ... 
   else
     ...
   fi
 fi
```

Comment: What *should* happen if res is null? Is that an error condition, or does it just not execute that code path?

Comment: if res is null, he jump to another section and continue read the code

Comment: not execute code path

Comment: If your code is structured with functions, you could return early from that function. Otherwise, what you have is just about as good as it gets (aside from `-n` vs `! -z`)

Answer (score 1):

Use `&&`.

```
if [[ ! -z "$res" && "$toto" -gt "$res" ]]
```

Other improvements you could make:

- Replace `! -z` with `-n`.
- Remove unnecessary quotes.
- Use `((...))` for numerical comparisons.

```
if [[ -n $res ]] && ((toto > res))
```

Comment: nope, because, for else statement he would be considered comparison value betwen null and $toto, so he must'nt do comparaison because, $res is null

Comment: so I don't want that -gt compare value if res=''
I want only compare if there is a number not a null value

Answer (score 0):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code handles empty `$res` in another way:

```
#! /bin/bash

res=''
toto=5
if [[ -z $res ]] ; then
    : # $res is empty so don't compare with $toto
elif ((  toto > res )); then
    echo 'toto is greater than res'
else
    echo 'toto is less than or equal to res'
fi
```

However, it's debatable whether it's better or worse than the "not very good" option suggested in the question.  Deeper nesting is usually worse, but if-the-else chains are best avoided.  The only advantage I would claim for the code in this answer is that it has a convenient place to put a helpful comment if one is useful.